# Change layout direction RTL LTR manajro

Tags: manjaro

I was setting up my manjaro, and all of a sudden I changed the layout from left to right, can't go back, I don't know what changed, I changed DE, I deleted the configs files but nothing changes.
An idea? On the windows manger side, I can't find anything. I don't know where the settings are.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, I changed the keybord layout, and it change all layout also.